# wordpress content filter causing image link to break

Tags: php, wordpress, utf-8, domdocument

I wrote a plug-in to remove links for non-registered members of a blog, however the plug-in has caused image links to become wrong, below is the content filter I wrote:

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    // Do nothing.  All is well.
} else {
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML($content);
    $dom_xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);

    foreach($doc->getElementsByTagName('a') as $link)
        $link->setAttribute('href', $UNREGISTERED_LINK_HREF);

    $texts = $dom_xpath->query('//a/child::text()');
    foreach ($texts as $text)
    {
        $text->data = $UNREGISTERED_LINK_TEXT;
    }

    $content = $doc->saveHTML();

}
```

The correct image link:
http://electrouniverse.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/Kyle-Geiger-%E2%80%93-Relentless-SOMA343D-240x240.jpg

After filtering the links:
http://electrouniverse.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/Kyle-Geiger-%C3%A2%C2%80%C2%93-Relentless-SOMA343D-240x240.jpg

I tried using utf8_decode() and utf8_encode() to work around this but it did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following before `$doc->loadHTML($content);`:

```
$content = mb_convert_encoding($content, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8');
```

Comment: I am not sure if this works, but I found another workaround so I will accept you since you are the only answer :D